# MS Office Macro Allowlisting

Tags: excel, vba, security, ms-word

In our company, we have a lot of - lets say - incautious coworkers. Because of a recent increase in Emotet threats, I want to block Office Macros, but some of our own office files (some of which are needed by said incautious coworkers) contain macros, so I can't turn macros off completely. I want to

1. allow macros from files in certain directories on the network
2. *completely* disallow them for all other locations
3. I absolutely don't want the users to be able to override the setting by clicking a button at the top of the window!
   [image]

We have moved to Office 2016 for this, as several tutorials like [this](https://4sysops.com/archives/restricting-or-blocking-office-2016-2019-macros-with-group-policy/) suggested and I have installed the [administrative templates](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030) on the domain controller. I'm currently testing this on my own machine - so I have applied the GPO only to my own machine and my own domain user account so far and I `gpupdate /force` after every change.

I have created a word document with a small "Hello World" VBA script to test this. I put that file into my Downloads directory (where the script should be disabled) and also C:\test and some \\server\share\dir\ and M:\dir which is a network drive mounted from \\server\share.

I have tested a lot of settings in the GPO, but none of them does what I want. Whatever I tried, it always either allows macros everywhere or disallows macros everywhere.

When I set `User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Office 2016 > Security Settings > Disable VBA for Office Applications`, I cannot run macros at all.

When I set `User configuration > Policies > Administrative templates > Microsoft Word 2016 > Word options > Security > Trust Center > VBA Macro Notification Setting` to `Disable all with notification` or `Disable all without notification`, I cannot run macros from anywhere. When I set it to one of the other values, I can run macros everywhere (although I haven't signed the file).

Settings in `User configuration > Policies > Administrative templates > Microsoft Office 2016 > Security settings > Trust Center > Trusted Location ...` do not seem to have *any* effect.

Does any one of you have experience with such a scenario? Am I doing something wrong or do I misunderstand the tutorials and This isn't even possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had stored the test-script globally in word, instead of locally in the file. That is why the location of the file had no influence on the outcome.